# Элемент имеет нулевые размеры при вызове offsetWidth offsetHeight в componenDidMount React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо в жизненном цикле `ComponentDidMount` компонента получить размеры элемента, для этого в методе `render()` я повесил ссылку на элемент:

```
public render() {
return (
  <div ref={this.gridRef} id="grid-widget" className="h-100 overflow-hidden w-100 p-0 d-flex flex-column">
    {this.renderGrid()}
  </div>
);
}
```

В ComponentDidMount получаю элемент и беру его размеры:

```
public componentDidMount() {
     this.props.recalculateGrid({ 
         width: this.gridRef.current.offsetWidth, 
         height: this.gridRef.current.offsetHeight 
     });
}
```

Но дело в том, что в данный момент размеры элемента w = 0 и h = 0. Хотя если открыть разметку, то элемент имеет размеры.
Причем до определенного момента это работало, после изменения стилей это сломалось, к сожалению, конкретное изменение сложно найти, но хотелось бы понять, почему так вообще происходит.
Можно ли повесить на элемент какой то коллбэк, который сработает тогда, когда у элемента будут размеры?

Answer (score 0):

Дело явно в стилях или в том, что соседние компоненты делают что-то асинхронно. Для того, чтобы сказать, что конкретно не так, в вопросе кода недостаточно. Обрати внимание, что хотя `componentDidMount` вызывается когда текущий элемент примонтирован, может оказаться, что последующие элементы (sibling) ещё нет (у меня с ангуляром была такая проблема).

Что касается второй части вопроса - можно ли отследить изменение размеров dom-элемента: в современных браузерах имеется [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), который предназначен именно для этого. Но это не означает, что стоит его бросаться использовать - вполне допускаю, что есть более хорошее решение, задействующее только css.

Answer (score 0):

**React** никак не отвечает за отрисовку стилей. цикл `componentDidMount` сработает тогда, когда у компонента будут смонтирована разметка и его логика. за отрисовку и перерисовку отвечают графические движки (например, **WebKit**) и сам *JS* движок (его **EventLoop**). это процесс банально называется `repaint/redraw`.

в результате, теоретически, **EventLoop** первоначально отрисовывает Ваш компонент, ставит в очередь **componentDidMount** и только после этого делает `redraw` Вашего документа

Comment: Это неверно. Обращение на чтение к текущим стилям вызовет reflow если они ещё не были просчитаны.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так `reflow` отвечает за изменения структуры DOM дерева, а не стилей

Comment: Как раз стилей.

Comment: @Qwertiy, допустим.  [вот первая статья из гугла](https://webo.in/articles/all/2009/31-rending-restyle-reflow-relayout/). глава **Перерисовка и перерасчет дерева отрисовки**

Comment: Понятия не имею, зачем ты мне дал эту ссылку, но ладно, вот нарезка из неё: _"Потребуется пересчитать некоторые части дерева перерисовки (...). Этот процесс называется перерасчет дерева отрисовки (reflow) ... Браузер может создать некоторую очередь, в которую будет вносить изменения, производимые скриптами, и выполнять эти изменения пачками. ... Но иногда скрипты могут предотвратить такое оптимизирующее поведение браузеров и заставить применить все накопившиеся в очереди изменения прямо сию секунду. Это происходит, когда вы запрашиваете следующую информацию о стилях ... offsetWidth"._

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я к Вам не **ты** не переключался) пожалуйста, соблюдайте дистанцию. но Вы всё равно (как и я, частично) оказались не правы.
прошу пересмотреть [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549296/whats-the-difference-between-reflow-and-repaint)

Comment: Я ко всем так обращаюсь. Ответ тот видел, в чём конкретно я неправ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Вы были правы. благодарю за дискуссию

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему. Пробовал useEffect это не помогло. Пробовал использовать setTimeout, иногда помогает, иногда вываливаются ошибки связанные с рекурсией. Пробовал MutationObserver, но, к сожалению, он не реагирует на изменение размеров блока.

Мне пришлось откатывать коммиты и смотреть когда этот баг пропадет. Хочу обратить внимание, что баг воспроизводится не с первого раза, иногда нужно несколько раз перезагрузить страницу.

Компонент Grid, с которым у меня была проблема лежит в контейнере. Помимо него в этом контейнере есть еще два компонента. Все три компонента я импортировал в контейнер с помощью lazy import. Я переписал это на обычные импорты.

Сам компонент контейнера вместе с другими компонентами (достаточно простыми) так же импортировался с помощью lazy import. Импорт контейнера я оставил на lazy, а вот у компонентов, которые импортировались рядом с этим контейнером я убрал lazy импорт и это помогло.

Но таким решением я не очень доволен, оно не чувствуется надежным. Так что я продолжаю поиски более надежного метода.

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте использовать `useLayoutEffect`
2. Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [react-resize-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resize-detector)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]